# How to convert "Mon, November 14, 2022 11:30 AM" to datetime in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I need help trying to convert "Mon, November 14, 2022 11:30 AM" to datetime in R.

```
strftime(as.POSIXct(as.Date("Mon, November 14, 2022 11:30 AM")), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UCT")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on `lubridate::mdy_hm`:

```r
x <- "Mon, November 14, 2022 11:30 AM"

lubridate::mdy_hm(x)

#> [1] "2022-11-14 11:30:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

The format for abbreviated weekday is `%a`

```
as.POSIXct("Mon, November 14, 2022 11:30 AM",
      format = "%a, %b %d, %Y %H:%M %p")
[1] "2022-11-14 11:30:00 EST"
```

---

Or can do this automatically with `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
parse_date("Mon, November 14, 2022 11:30 AM")
[1] "2022-11-14 11:30:00 UTC"
```